# MySQL - EXIT Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <PROC_NAME>
    BEGIN
        CALL PROC1;
        CALL PROC2;
        CALL PROC3;
    END;
```

In all the above 3 calls, I have added DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION `CALL PROC_ERROR('Proc_Name');`

Now let's say there is a sqlexception in PROC2 and the control goes to PROC_ERROR where I execute ROLLBACK statement.
After the call PROC_ERROR execution, the control still continues and it executes PROC3 procedure which should not happen.
Ideally I want to end the execution as soon as the ROLLBACK is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your exception handler, after the ROLLBACK statement, you need to raise another exception.  You can achieve this by using a RESIGNAL statement.  See this for detail:  http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2009/7/13/signal-and-resignal-in-mysql-54-and-60.html  Because the RESIGNALed exception will not be handled, execution will end as soon as the ROLLBACK is completed.